# Asp.Net 3.5 explicit localization with web application

Tags: asp.net, localization

On an asp.net 3.5 application I am trying to explicitly localize text. Example below from MSDN

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" Runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, Msg1 %>">
```

The problem is it can't seem to find the resource class. I am using an asp.net application, not website. I've tried specifying the full namespace for the resource class. e.g:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" Runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:MyProject.Web.Properties.Resources, Msg1 %>">
```

But no avail. Any ideas?

Forgot to mention...if I use databinding expression like this, it works:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" Runat="server" Text="<% MyProject.Web.Properties.Resources.Msg1 %>">
```

**Update:**

After spending a little time with reflector came across this in the ResourceExpressionBuilder:

```
private static IResourceProvider GetGlobalResourceProvider(string classKey)
{
    string str = "Resources." + classKey;
    CacheInternal cacheInternal = HttpRuntime.CacheInternal;
    string key = "A" + str;
    IResourceProvider provider = cacheInternal[key] as IResourceProvider;
    if (provider == null)
    {
        EnsureResourceProviderFactory();
        provider = s_resourceProviderFactory.CreateGlobalResourceProvider(classKey);
        cacheInternal.UtcInsert(key, provider);
    }
    return provider;
}
```

So it looks like it is expecting a namespace of Resources.xxx. My current resource file resides in WebApp > Properties > Resources with the web application's namespace. Think that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten it to work with this:

```
<asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:PageResource1.Title %>" />
```

My resource is in the `App_LocalResources` folder in a file with the name `PageName.aspx.resx`. My resource key name is `PageResource1.Title`.

For a global resource ( `App_GlobalResource\ErrorMessages.resx` ), this seemed to work:

```
<%$ Resources:ErrorMessages, ErrorHasOccurred %>
```